# Getting the 1st file name when grouping together files by file extension

Tags: c#, linq

I have parent folder with sub-folders.

All the files have an extension that is a guid I generated. The guids can be the same or not.

The filename is the timestamp of the file.

At present I get the count of each group using this code:

```
var query = Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\\Catalogues", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
   .GroupBy(file => Path.GetExtension(file))
   .Select(grp => new
   {
       Extension = grp.Key,
       Count = grp.Count()
   }).ToList();
```

I need to get the 1st occurrence of the filename of each of these 'groups' I could do a separate linq to do this but I was wondering whether it can be done all in 1 linq statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can be done just like you calculate count of files in each group

```
var query = Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\\Catalogues", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
   .GroupBy(file => Path.GetExtension(file))
   .Select(grp => new
   {
       Extension = grp.Key,
       FileName = grp.First(),
       Count = grp.Count()
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks but I get an error  telling me that that 'string does not contain a definition for Name'

Comment: I got to wait 9 mins before accepting your answer but i will asap

Comment: @AndrewSimpson, also possible `FileName = Path.GetFileName(grp.First())`, if you don't need full path to file